# ¿Recorrer un fichero y la salida guardarla en variables para hacer una funcion FTP?

Tags: python, ftp

```
login.txt
# Contenido del fichero login.txt
- ['10.0.0.3','Root','*****','/usr/amat','C:\Users\becario2adm','yyyymmdd']
- ['10.0.0.4','Administrador','*******','/zzz','C:\Users\becario2adm','yyyy_mm_dd']
- ['10.0.0.5','Administrador','*******','/','C:\Users\becario2adm','yyyy_mm_dd']
```

pruebaFtp.py

```
import yaml
with open("login.txt") as f:
    data = yaml.safe_load(f)

for elemento in data:
    print(elemento[0], elemento[1],elemento[2], elemento[3],elemento[4], elemento[5])

from ftplib import FTP

funcion ftp()
ftp = FTP(dirServer)
ftp.login(user=usuario, passwd=passwd)
```

¿Como puedo hacer para que cada linea que leo de login.txt coja el elemento 0 del array y lo guarde en una variable dirServer, el elemento [1] lo guarde en una variable usuario, y el elemento [2]?

Así sucesivamente y usar esas variables para hacer tantas conexiones Ftp como lineas haya en login.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prácticamente te has respondido tú mismo:

> ¿Como puedo hacer para que cada linea que leo de login.txt coja el elemento 0 del array y lo guarde en una variable dirServer, el elemento [1] lo guarde en una variable usuario, y el elemento [2]?

Traduciendo tu español al python:

```
dirServer = elemento[0]
usuario = elemento[1]
passwd = elemento[2]
```

etc.. Pero esto es la sintaxis básica de asignación de variables, por lo que no entiendo la duda. Seguramente estás preguntando otra cosa.

En cuanto a repetir conexiones para cada elemento del fichero, basta meter el código que hace esas conexiones dentro del mismo bucle en que imprimes los valores. Así, en cada iteración del bucle imprime unos valores diferentes, *y los usa* como parámnetros para las correspondientes conexiones. Esta es la idea:

```
from ftplib import FTP
import yaml

with open("login.txt") as f:
    data = yaml.safe_load(f)

for elemento in data:
    print(elemento[0], elemento[1],elemento[2], elemento[3],elemento[4], elemento[5])

    dirServer = elemento[0]   
    usuario = elemento[1]
    passwd = elemento[2]
    # etc...

    ftp = FTP(dirServer)
    ftp.login(user=usuario, passwd=passwd)
    # etc...
```

De todas formas no entiendo exactamente dónde se te plantea la duda. Es un mero bucle estándar, que se repite tantas veces como elementos tenga la lista `data`, es decir, tantas veces como servidores tengas configurado en el archivo yaml.

Comment: tengo el concepto pero no se escribir en código

Comment: Pues quizás deberías comenzar por algún tutorial básico, sobre variables, bucles, listas... antes de ponerte con cosas complicadas como conexiones ftp. En internet tienes cientos por donde empezar. El tiempo que "pierdes" estudiando lo básico lo ganas con creces más adelante. Fíjate todo el tiempo que llevas ya con este problema tan sencillo (pues lo de procesar la lista en bucle era lo más fácil, lo de conectar por FTP que era lo peor ya lo tenías resuelto)

Comment: saludos @antoniop ninguno de los usuarios estan obligados a responder, si consideras que algun comentario fue fuera de lo comun te invito a escribir en el [Meta de stackoverflow](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/)